# Possible gradient issue with custom activation function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need a custom activation function formulated below:

[image]

Here is how I implement it with tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()

def s_lamda_activation(f, lam):
    positive = tf.nn.relu(f - lam)
    positive = positive * (f/positive)
    positive = tf.where(tf.is_nan(positive), tf.zeros_like(positive), positive)
    negative = tf.nn.relu((-f) - lam)
    negative = negative * (f/negative)
    negative = tf.where(tf.is_nan(negative), tf.zeros_like(negative), negative)
    return positive + negative


a = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,5,10,-10,14,-20],[-100,-2,-3,-4,-5,-10,10,-14,-20]], dtype=tf.float32)
a = s_lamda_activation(a, 5)
print(sess.run(a))
```

Output:

```
[[   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   10.  -10.   14.  -20.]
 [-100.    0.    0.    0.    0.  -10.   10.  -14.  -20.]]
```

However, the `tf.where` may cause some gradient issues and the loss is not decreasing using this implementation.

I deleted the `tf.where` and changed the code to:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()

def s_lamda_activation(f, lam):
    positive = tf.nn.relu(f - lam)
    negative = tf.nn.relu((-f) - lam)
    return positive - negative


a = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,5,10,-10,14,-20],[-100,-2,-3,-4,-5,-10,10,-14,-20]], dtype=tf.float32)
a = s_lamda_activation(a, 5)
print(sess.run(a))
```

Output:

```
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   5.  -5.   9. -15.]
 [-95.   0.   0.   0.   0.  -5.   5.  -9. -15.]]
```

This implementation works fine and the loss function is decreasing as expected. But this implementation is not the same as the original activation function formulated above. Any suggestions for me to implement the function correctly and efficiently? And would the `tf.where` generate gradient issue?

Really appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't use `tf.where()` correctly to implement your activation function. You can use `tf.gradients` to see your gradient as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

...

result = s_lamda_activation(a, 5)
grad = tf.gradients(result,a)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))
    print(sess.run(grad))
[[   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   10.  -10.   14.  -20.]
 [-100.    0.    0.    0.    0.  -10.   10.  -14.  -20.]]
[array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]], dtype=float32)]
```

The correct usage is simple:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def s_lamda_activation(f, lam):
    return tf.where(tf.greater(tf.abs(f),lam),f,tf.zeros_like(f))

a = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,5,10,-10,14,-20],[-100,-2,-3,-4,-5,-10,10,-14,-20]], dtype=tf.float32)

result = s_lamda_activation(a, 5)
grad = tf.gradients(result,a)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))
    print(sess.run(grad))

[[   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   10.  -10.   14.  -20.]
 [-100.    0.    0.    0.    0.  -10.   10.  -14.  -20.]]
[array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32)]
```